# Why every component of a loopless matroid is flat?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics

Why every component of a loopless matroid is flat?

I know that the rank of a loop in a matroid is zero and I read that: A loop is an element of a matroid that is not contained in any independent set (is this because it has rank zero so it may be considered as dependent set?), or equivalently, an element that is contained in all flats (why is this correct?).

Also, can the previous paragraph help me by any means in understanding the first question I proposed?

**Edit:**

I also know that an element $e$ is a loop of $M$ if and only if $e$ is not in any of the bases of $M.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this because it has rank zero so it may be considered as dependent
> set?

Yes, $X$ is independent iff $r(X)=|X|$.

> an element that is contained in all flats. why is this correct?

Well, a loop $e$ has rank zero, so if $e\not \in X$, submodularity tells you that $r(X\cup e)\leq r(X)+r(e)=r(X)$ and so $r(X)=r(X\cup e)$ so $e$ is in every clausure, so its in every flat. If $e$ is not in some flat, then you can use submodularity too to check that its rank is bigger than zero.

> Why every component of a loopless matroid is flat?

Let $A$ be a component and suppose that $A\subset cl_M(A)$. Now, consider $x\in cl_M(A)\setminus A$, so there exists $A'\subseteq A$ such that $A'\cup \{x\}$ is a circuit, and notice that $A'$ is non-empty because we have no loops, then $x$ is in the component $A$ (recall that the definition is that they are equivalence classes under the relation of being in a circuit) which is a contradiction, then $A=cl_M(A)$ and so $A$ is a flat.

Comment: How did you know this idea "consider $x\in cl_M(A)\setminus A$, so there exists $A'\subseteq A$ such that $A'\cup \{x\}$ is a circuit"?

Comment: So you assumed towards contradiction that there is an element in the closure of A that is not in A and you arrived at a contradiction. Right?

Comment: It is not very clear to me what is the contradiction you reached. Could you clarify please?

Comment: As an answer to the question in my first comment, I believe you are using proposition 1.4.11(ii) in matroid theory, second edition by James  Oxley, right? But the circuit does not have to be equal $A' \cup  x$ it is just a subset of it, am I correct?

Comment: I did not get why having no loops in the matroid M makes $A'$  nonempty.could you clarify please?

Comment: @Secretly Well, I didn't know of proposition 1.4.11, but yes, that is exactly what I am using. Well the subset is already $A'$. It is non-empty because if it was empty, then $\{x\}$ is a circuit, hence a loop.